# Is there a way to create "snap to surface" constraint?

Tags: animation, constraints

https://i.imgur.com/K8rOWnm.mp4
Here's a visual example of what I want to make (I did it by using "snap during transform" on "face" mode)

basically I want to create a camera that's always offset X amount of distance from floor that's under it automatically, just Z axis to be constrained

I already tried using floor constraint but it never really works

please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Shrinkwrap Constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/shrinkwrap.html) will snap the camera to a surface.

Add the *Shrinkwrap Constraint* to your camera, select your floor shape as *Target* and adjust the *distance*.

[image]

I recommend adding a *Copy Location Constraint* to your Camera, with the *x* and *y* axis targeted to an *Empty*. It makes it easier to control the camera animation, see above.

[image]

Comment: Yeah this seems the most straight forward way to do that!  This is what my solution ended up looking like https://i.imgur.com/2oZN98G.mp4

Answer (score 2):

Tell me if this is what you want:

- Create a plane, go in Edit mode, *W* > *Subdivide* a bit and assign the whole mesh a Group name in *Properties* > *Data* > *Vertex Groups*.
- Give your Camera a *Copy Location* constraint, choose the plane as the *Target*, then choose the *Group*. Click *Offset* and move the Camera until it is over the plane at the place you want.
- Give your plane a *Shrinkwrap* modifier and choose the ground as your *Target*.
- Move your plane, the Camera should follow the ground on the same Z distance all along.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer @moonboots!  But I didn't manage to make it work, because it appears to be that copy location constraint is calculated before shrink warp modifier, so camera isn't affected by plane being projected on ground

here's an example of what I mean https://i.imgur.com/JJszLuv.mp4

Comment: It should work, and Copy Location is for camera, Shrinkwrap for the plane, but anyway, Garulfo proposed a simpler solution, I didn't know camera had Shrinkwrap constraint   ;)