# How to get a hover craft effect (Object over Landscape)?

Tags: animation, transforms, constraints, blend-files

I have made a hilly landscape using the **Landscape addon** in **blender 2.8**.
I have an object which I want to animate across the landscape by following the surface contours and maintaining a small distance, a little *like a hovercraft floating over the land*.
I have tried the “**Limit Distance constraint**” but can’t seem to make it work.

Is there a FAST and EASY way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Shrinkwrap constraint is pretty good for this,  to control how far your object is from the ground you can simply lift it in edit mode to move it's origin downward.

Comment: How would you set this up?

Comment: I have given this a go but the object is still passing into the landscape here and there. I already have key framing on the object so would this be the reason that I am having problems?

Comment: Yeah you need to keep it's position above the landscape for the projection to work, otherwise it will go through.

Comment: Ok, I got it working, but the animation looks a little jerky at some points along the timeline. Is there some way to smooth it out? Here is the link to my file if it helps in determining the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wrpx0rf8fd3w7go/Santa%20scene%2014.blend?dl=0

Comment: Choose Shrinkwrap Type > Target Normal Project, Snap Mode > Outside Surface, enable Align Axis To Normal and click on the Z axis, it seems to work fine

Comment: Also, I gave an alternative solution here that might give a different result, you need to test: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114774/is-there-a-way-to-create-snap-to-surface-constraint

Answer (score 0):

[image: final]

Fast and easy way would be to:

1. Create a little **Plane**.
2. Parent **Object** to this **Plane**.
3. Turn on **Face Snap**. Optionally check **Align Rotation to Target**.

   [image]
4. Move the **Plane**.

[image: setup]

Comment: This doesn't rotate with the landscape though, I would think that's what the author would want

Comment: @ArthurBlaquart Check edit - point 3.

Comment: This kind of snapping wouldn't work when rendering, this is only to help you setting up your scene and modeling