# Position a sphere on a heightmap

Tags: animation, drivers, height-map

In my scene I have a heightmap (that is, a plane with a displace modifier) and a sphere. I want the z coordinate of the sphere to automatically match that of the heightmap when I animate the sphere's (x, y) coordinates. Any solution (including bpy, drivers, etc...) is welcome.

[image]

Comment: i assume that you don't want a "trivial" solution with z-coordinate of plane + displacement + radius is not enough? So you also want that the sphere does not collide with "hills" nearby?

Comment: please check this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114774/is-there-a-way-to-create-snap-to-surface-constraint

Comment: similarly https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175503/15543